# Get the Asymptotic Notation of The Run time

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have the runtime below:

```
  T(n) = (1- (1/2^n)) ((n+1)/2)
```

I know its upperbound can be something like : O(2^n)

But I couldn't find its lowerbound or omega. Is it possible that an algorithm has no lower bound? What about theta ? little oh and little omega?

Comment: Your big-O is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust--Why?

Comment: Check the two answers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is not wrong, indeed. It is not tight.

Comment: @OmG: technically speaking, you are right. But it is clear that the OP misintepreted the expression.

Answer (score 2):

The inverse exponential is negligible in front of 1, so `Θ(n)`, which implies all other bounds.

Answer (score 1):

As `1- 1/2^n >= 0.5` for all `n >= 1`, we can say `T(n) >= 0.5(n+1)/2 = (n+1) /4`. Hence, `T(n) = \Omega(n)`. Also, as `1- 1/2^n < 2` for all `n >= 0`, `T(n) <= n + 1` we can say `T(n) = O(n)`. Therefore, we can say `T(n) = \Theta(n)`.

Comment: How did you came up with 0.25 in the equation 0.25(n+1)/2 ? Please englighten me :)

Comment: Why are you separating (1- (1/2^n)) and ((n+1)/2).  They are on the same equation.

Comment: @Eliyah I've split them to simplify the part of `1-1/2^n`. As, this part of the equation can be bounded from its upper and lower, in contrast with `(n+1)/2` which cannot be bounded from its upper.

Comment: Okay, I get it but how do you came up with 0.25(n+1)/2? Sorry but please let me understand this :)

Comment: @Eliyah just replace the minimum value of the `1 - 1/2^n` part.

Comment: What about T(n) <= n + 1 ?  How did it happen?

Comment: @Eliyah The same. Instead of the lower bound, upper bound of the specified term is replaced.

Comment: So what do you think  the upper bound is?